# set jenkins user build variable option is not available even after installed build user vars

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have "Build User Vars"(user build vars plugin - V 1.5) plugin installed in Jenkins(Version 1.565) but in the job configuration, "set jenkins user build variable" checkbox option is not available. Could someone please help me in understanding what is wrong with my Jenkins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must **upgrade your Jenkins** to at least version 1.609. If you cannot, **downgrade the plugin** to version 1.4.

See the [plugin changelog](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) for details.

Comment: This Works! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @AlexO  Can we change the username for who started the build ?

Answer (score 1):

If your Jenkins' version is greater than 1.609 and you still can't find it in the configuration, in order to access the plugins' variables simply wrap the code in the Jenkinsfile with "BuildUser" class as so:

```
 wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
      echo "BUILD_USER=${BUILD_USER}"
      echo "env.BUILD_USER_EMAIL=${env.BUILD_USER_EMAIL}"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of the plugin "build user vars" is not really easy to understand.

Here some examples working for me:

```
stage('Pluto') {
  steps {
    sh " sleep 2"
    sh "echo 'pluto'"
    wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
      sh "echo '${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}'"
    }
  }
}


post {
    success {
        wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
          sh " echo '${BUILD_USER_EMAIL}'"
        }
    }
}
```